# Data from useRef renders only after changing the code and saving it

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, axios

I'm having an issue with my react app. I retrieve data from my elasticsearch server and trying to display it on the website.

```
const RecipesPage = (props: Props) => {                                                             
      const recipes = useRef<Recipe[]>([]);                                                             
      const avCategories = ['meats', 'pastas', 'vegan', 'seafood', 'desserts', 'all'];                  
      const currentCategory = props.match.params.category_name.toLowerCase();                           
                                                                                                        
      useEffect(() => {                                                                                 
        const recipesReq = getRecipesByCategory(currentCategory);                                       
        recipesReq                                                                                      
          .then((data) => recipes.current = data.hits.hits)                                             
      }, [currentCategory])                                                                             
                                                                                                                    
      if (avCategories.includes(currentCategory)) {                                                                 
        return (                                                                                                    
          <div>                                                                                                     
            <Navbar />                                                                                  
            <ul style={{marginTop: "5.5rem"}}>{recipes.current.map((recipe: Recipe) => <p key={recipe._id}>{recipe._source.recipe_name}</p>)}</ul>
          </div>                                                                                        
        );                                                                                                                                       
      } else {                                                                                                                                   
        return (                                                                                                                                 
          <div>                                                                                         
            <Navbar />                                                                                  
            <p style={{marginTop: "5.5rem"}}>No category named {currentCategory}</p>                    
          </div>                                                                                        
        );                                                                                              
      }                                                                                                 
    };                                                                                                  
                                                                                                        
  export default RecipesPage
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to display the data it shows up only after saving the code and then after refreshing the page it's gone. I guess it's a problem related to useRef hook, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should be using state, not a ref. The only way react knows to rerender is if you set state.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but there is another problem in that case and it's that if I use state inside of the useEffect, it runs in an infinite loop until it fills all the memory space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use state if you need the component to rerender.
When using `useEffect`, you shouldn't pass an array or object reference as a dependency. React uses referential comparison to check for changes, which means the `useEffect` hook will run every time a new object/array is created regardless if the actual data changes, which can cause an infinite render loop:
https://www.benmvp.com/blog/object-array-dependencies-react-useEffect-hook/